# Finding the radius/interval of convergence of: $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}{k(\ln k)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Finding the radius of convergence and the interval of convergence of

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^k}{k(\ln k)^2}$$

Maybe using $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{u_{n+1}(x)}{u_n(x)}\right|=\dfrac{1}{R}$?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut...sorry i edited

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. For $|x|\leq 1$, one has
$$
\left|\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^k}{k(\ln k)^2}\right|\leq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \left| \frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}{k(\ln k)^2}\right|\leq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1{k(\ln k)^2}<\infty,
$$ the latter series being convergent by the [integral  test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence): $\displaystyle \int_2^\infty \frac{dt}{t(\ln t)^2}=\int_{\ln 2}^\infty \frac{du}{u^2}=\frac1{\ln 2}.$

For $|x|>1$, one has
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\left|(-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^k}{k(\ln k)^2}\right|=\infty \neq0.
$$

Comment: ..what is the radius of the series

Comment: @Psuresh If you recall the definition of the radius of a power series, you may deduce that the radius is $R=1$, the interval of convergence is exactely $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @ jean..sorry if i ask anything wrong i am little confusing what is the radius

Comment: @Olivier..so radius of converges is 1 and and this series convergent in [-1,1]..rihgt

Comment: but i am not get the radius 1..can you solve it please

Comment: @Psuresh What is,  for you, the definition of the radius of convergence?

Comment: the formula i have witten in the question board

Comment: @Psuresh Please, have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Definition

Comment: so we can use any of the formula for finding radius right

Comment: ..i am got  0 is the radius of convergence..please if u dont min can you solve it

Comment: Here, I did not use any formula, I've used *definition*. I've proved that the power series is convergent for $|x|\leq1$ and the series is divergent for $|x|>1$. All this yields that $R=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you mentioned in your question actually isn't true.  It's
$$ \lim_{n\to+\infty} \left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} \right| = \frac{1}{R}.$$

The $c_n$ are the coefficients of the terms in the series.  When you say $u_n(x)$ I'm interpreting that to be the entire $n$th term, **including** the $x$.  To use this formula you need to not have the $x$ in it.

We have:
$$c_n = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}$$

So then:
$$c_{n+1} = (-1)^{n+2} \frac{1}{(n+1) [\ln (n+1)]^2}$$

And:
\begin{align}
  \lim_{n\to +\infty} \left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right|
    &= \lim_{n\to +\infty} \left|c_{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{c_n}\right|\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{n\to+\infty} \left|(-1)^{n+2} \frac{1}{(n+1) [\ln (n+1)]^2}\cdot (-1)^{n+1} \frac{n (\ln n)^2}{1} \right|\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{n (\ln n)^2}{(n+1) [\ln(n+1)]^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= 1\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{1}{R}
\end{align}

So we see that $\dfrac{1}{R} = 1$, therefore $R = 1$.  Since the original series just has $x^n$ (as opposed to, for example, $(x-3)^n$) then we can find the interval of convergence by solving the inequality $|x| < 1$ for $x$.  It's trivial and is just $-1 < x < 1$.  Then we have to individually test both $x=1$ and $x=-1$ in the series to see if either or both endpoints should be included in the answer.  I'll leave that last bit to you.